# JSF exception deploying to FireFly, tag named inputFile null handler-class

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I am trying to learn JSF and am having a problem deploying any project.  I have installed the following:

Eclipse Kepler release 2
JBoss tools for eclipse
WildFly 8
Maven 3.2.1
Java JDK 8
mojarra 2.2.6

I am having this problem with JSF projects I create and downloaded sample project.  When I deploy the project to WildFly in eclipse it throws the exception:

```
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start: service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Test: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Test: Failed to start service
```

The Test.war.failed file in the deployment folder of WildFly has the following:

```
"{\"JBAS014671: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Test\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Test: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined\"}}"
```

Also, I don't know if this is related, but when I open the faces-config.xml file in eclipse it doesn't show the page with all the tabs that the many web examples show.  It only has tabs for Diagram, Tree, and Source.  Is this because the examples are JSF 2.0 and I am using JSF 2.2.6?

Answer (score 21):

Please remove Mojarra from the dependencies. WildFly already ships with an JSF implementation and if you deploy one with your app, you run into such problems.

Comment: Thanks so much, removing the external library fixed the deployment problem.

Comment: @JohnB: How can I do that? In eclipse right click on top folder in Project Explorer and open Properties. Choose Deployment Assembly and remove Majarra from Web Deployment Assembly. Restart WildFly.

Comment: I have added "provided" in my maven dependencies:         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the dynamic web project with JSF 2.1 instead 2.2 resolved the issue for me once...
and then once again the same error and updating web.xml as follows worked fine...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```